# sonarqube and aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, sonarqube

I recently enabled sonarqube for my lambda functions.
Now as we all know, for any lambda_handler this is the standard process. However all the logics are stated and based on event not much on context.

`def lambda_handler(event, context):`

Now after running the sonarqube scan, I'm getting:
`Remove the unused function parameter "context".`
I'm getting MAJOR issue from the sonarqube for all my lambdas , any suggestion to fix this issue?
My lambdas are Python based.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here, so I just decided to print any attribute of the context instance, so it was some thing like this:

```
print(context.invoked_function_arn) # you can use logger instead of printing
```

And that solved it, but I guess the most fancy way would to fix this is to ignore the lambda_handler files to be analyzed by SQ.

In case you already fixed this, please share how you did it please!